# Nginx+Passenger: 502 Bad Gateway from Nginx when passing urlencoded URLs in GET vars

Tags: nginx, ruby-on-rails, phusion-passenger, 500-error

Here's an example of the URLs that don't work:

```
http://domain/do?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.linkedin.com%2Fin%2Fperson
http://domain/do?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.linkedin.com%2F
```

However, the following URL does work:

```
http://domain/do?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.linkedin.com
```

Also, this only happens with Nginx, using Passenger with Apache it works fine, but we use Nginx on our production machines.

Here's the entry in Nginx's error log:

```
2009/12/01 09:30:51 [error] 6407#0: *136 upstream prematurely closed connection while reading response header from upstream, client: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx, server: domain, request: "GET /do?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.linkedin.com%2F HTTP/1.1", upstream: "passenger://unix:/tmp/passenger.6335/master/helper_server.sock:", host: "domain"
```

Comment: What lib did you have an issue with?

Answer (score 1):

It has nothing to do with Nginx or Passenger.

There was a library that takes and uses a URL wasn't working with the Ruby version on our production server. For some odd reason it was causing Rails to fail so catastrophically that the only erros were in Nginx's error log.